# Can't change arrows on accordion

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to replicate the accordion from W3C. My project is spread across 4 folders: CSS, FONTS, IMAGES and SCRIPT. The problem is that JS doesn't want to toggle the background images. Here is my code.

CSS

```
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  border-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #515151;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-image: url(../IMAGES/arrow-right.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 330px 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS

```
for (i = 0; i < accordion.length; i++) {
  accordion[i].onclick = function() {
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show');

    if (this.textContent === 'Click to open') {
      this.textContent = 'Click to close';
    } else {
      this.textContent = 'Click to open';
    }

    if (this.style.backgroundImage === 'url(../IMAGES/arrow-right.png)') {
      this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(../IMAGES/arrow-down.png)';
    } else {
      this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(../IMAGES/arrow-right.png)';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is accordion defined as? Where's the associated HTML?

Comment: The accordion is made up of buttons which open divs. The HTML is located in the main folder which contains the 4 folders I mentioned above.

Comment: Show us the accordion declaration and the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to just make one arrow image. and add/remove classes on arrow with jquery/js and making a rotate `transform: rotate(90deg);` / transition like `transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;` for it to rotate.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I put the images in the main folder and everythimg is working propperly now.